# if $||\nabla f_1(x,y)||\leq a, ||\nabla f_2(x,y)||\leq a$ then $f$ is a contraction

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a funcion of class $C^1$ and supose that  there exists $a\in(0,\frac {\sqrt2} 2)$ such that $$\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2, ||\nabla f_1(x,y)||\leq a,  ||\nabla f_2(x,y)||\leq a$$
> Where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the components of the function $f$. Prove that $f$ is a contraction.

I was able to prove that for any $X,Y\in \mathbb R^2$, then: $$|f_i(Y)-f_i(X)|\leq a||Y-X||$$
for $i=1,2$.

After this I did the following: $$||f(Y) - f(X)||=||(f_1(Y) - f_1(X), f_2(Y)-f_2(X))||$$ $$\leq |f_1(Y) - f_1(X)| + |f_2(Y) - f_2(X)|$$ $$\leq 2a||Y-X|| \leq\sqrt 2 ||Y-X||$$

And I'm not being able to conclude that $f$ is a contraction. How can this be done?

Comment: Being a contraction depend on the norm you use. Are you sure that $\|\cdot \| $ is not the euclidian norm ?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it is the euclidian norm. We never used any norm other than the euclidian norm @Surb

Comment: So why do you upper bound by the $1-$norm ? If the Euclidian norm is used, then  $$\|f(Y)-f(X)\|\leq a\sqrt{2}\|X-Y\|,$$ what prove that $f$ is a contraction...